# How to control Apple media from Android device

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, avrcp, bluetooth-profile

According to [this page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204387) my Apple device supports AVRCP 1.4.

According to [this one](https://source.android.com/devices/bluetooth/services#bluetooth-profiles) my Android 8.0 device also supports AVRCP 1.4.

However according to [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth#Profiles) Android Bluetooth API only allows me access to **Headset**, **A2DP** and **Health Device** profiles, so why the second link is saying that **AVRCP** is supported? Is it supported by low level API and there is no high level API?

My goal is to control media being played on Apple device from Android device **without using MFI** program. I thought that AVRCP will be best for this purpose but currently I'm struggling with writing even some very basic app which would just do play / pause.

I've tried `listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord` with AVRCP UUID 
(`"0000110E-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"`) using `BluetoothAdapter`. I've tried `createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord` with this UUID using `BluetoothDevice` and I've also tried some hidden API like that:

```
boolean result = mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(this, listener, /*BluetoothProfile.AVRCP_CONTROLLER*/ 12);
```

`result` was true but nothing happened or I didn't know what to do next.

Do you have any tips? Maybe there is some problem which I'm unaware of?